# SAML maxAuthenticationAge in spring-security

Tags: spring, spring-security

In spring-security-saml, maxAuthenticationAge can be set as follows:

```
@Bean 
public WebSSOProfileConsumer getWebSSOProfileConsumerImpl(){
    WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl consumer = new WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl();
    consumer.setMaxAuthenticationAge(5000);
    return consumer;
}
```

What is the equivalent of the above in spring-security since WebSSOProfileConsumer doesnt exist?